# SendGrid v3 API - Send Mail Using Template with Empty/No Content

Tags: c#, .net, sendgrid

I am attempting to send email using SendGrid v3.

I am using the official csharp nuget package: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/

I wish to use a **Transactional Template** in which I have a series of **Substitution Tags** defined. Simple substitution values like `-firstname-` etc.

The Transactional Template that I defined basically has ALL of the required information/content/body defined it already. I only wish to use this template and have the substitution tags replaced with the `Personalization.SubstututionTags` that I define in the payload.

The documentation suggests that I MUST send `content` in the payload - in fact it is documented that I will receive an **Error Status Code of  400** if I send an email without any 'content'.

> https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#-Content-Errors
>
> The content param is required.    You may not send an email without the
>   content parameter. This is to prevent you from sending an empty email
>   to your recipients.

What should I include in the `content` if I simply want the content from the template to be used?

If I include some arbitrary content such as

```
      'content': [
        {
          'type': 'text/html',
          'value': 'I\'m replacing the <strong>body tag</strong>'
        }
      ],
```

Won't it overwrite the content from the template with that?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the other way around. The Template body will be populated, and whatever you send in the `content` of the API call will be [put in the Template](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Transactional_Templates/create_edit.html#-Editing-Your-Template) wherever you have `<%body%>`.

You do have to pass content in the API call, but it can just be `""`. And you do have to put the `<%body%>` tag in the Template, but it can be commented out: `<!-- <%body%> -->`.

This is a requirement that SendGrid understands causes this hurdle, and they're working on removing it, but don't have an ETA yet.

Comment: Not sure if API has changed, but when sending empty string just now I got this error: `{"errors":[{"message":"The content value must be a string at least one character in length.","field":"content.0.value","help":"http://sendgrid.com/...`